# Powershell Regex find name VPN connection

Tags: powershell, extract, vpn

I have a script to disconnect VPN (powershell):

```
$vpnName = "MyVPN";
$vpn = Get-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName;

if($vpn.ConnectionStatus -eq "Connected"){
  rasdial $vpnName /DISCONNECT;
}
```

Please tell me, how I can find and set var $vpnName if I know just part of VPN name, like "vash", full VPN name maybe VPNvashinsider or VPN vashinsider or vpnvashinsider.com

I need regex how I can set var $vpnName taked from part of word "vash"?

Comment: It is a string and you can use Contains : if($vpn.Name.Contains('vash'))

Comment: Thx ) and next step if($vpn.Name.Contains('vash')) | rasdial $vpnName /DISCONNECT; any way to set $vpnName real VPN name what contain "vash"? Can you example full script please?

Comment: $vpn = Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where-Object  { $_.Name -like '\*vash\*' }

Comment: To debug do it in two steps.  First get names and make sure you get valid results.  What are the results from query of names?  Like requires the two asterisks.

Comment: Work part of script: $vpn = Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'vash' } | rasdial $vpnName /DISCONNECT;

Comment: But second step can't complite full script... where wrong? $vpn = Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'vash' } | Set-VPNconnection -name $vpn -SplitTunneling $false

Comment: You will also need : $vpn | foreach { Set-VPNconnection -name $_.Name -SplitTunneling $false }